# Получение значения тега <span...>

Tags: python

Как на python вытащить текст из тега ?

```
for rows in table.find_all('tr'):
    names = rows.find_all('td')
    inform.append({
        'NAME' : names[0].span.
    })
```

Допустим, был бы тег `<a>`, то внутренности можно было бы получить с помощью `names[0].a.text`. А как быть тут? Если оставить `span` без атрибута, то выводит следующее:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом :

```
for rows in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        names = rows.find_all('td')
        value = rows.find('span')
        if value == None:
            continue
        inform.append({
            'Name': value.text
        })
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ну если с `<a>` работает `names[0].a.text`, то логично, что для span'а будет `names[0].span.text`.

Comment: К сожалению, выводит это:
'NAME' : names[0].span.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @ЮрийСмирнов, `names[0].find('span').text`?